# How to show that a map is smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a set $K = \{(x,y,z) \; \mathbb{R}^3| \; x^3+y^2+z^2 = \pi\}$ and a map $f: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ defined as
$$
f(x,y,z) = (x^6, -x, y, z)
$$

How do I show that $f$ is smooth? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I'm not looking for the solution, but I'm not sure where to even start here since I'm self-learning the material. Do I need to cover $K$ with charts and then show that compositions of $f$ with those charts are smooth?

Comment: Do I need to find a parameterization of $K$, call it $P: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow K$, and then show that $f \circ P$ is smooth? Sorry, I'm very new to differential geometry

Comment: That would work, but the parametrization would be defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, not $\mathbb{R}^3$, as It's a two-dimensional manifold (a sphere of radius $\sqrt{\pi}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is the restriction to $K$ of a smooth map $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$. As a restriction of a smooth map, it's smooth, because it's just the composition $f= F\circ i$, where $i:K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is the inclusion map (which is smooth because $K$ is a submanifold).

That's one way to prove it. You can also do what you are saying and check that it is a smooth function of any coordinates.

Comment: Look carefully, by the way; it's not a sphere! It's not even compact. Your argument is fine once you actually check that $K$ is a submanifold. However, this isn't necessary, as smoothness is defined, more generally, by having local smooth extensions, and here is a global smooth extension.